# Set dash style in matplotlibrc

Tags: python, matplotlib

Can I define the dash style, i.e. length and separation, in the matplotlibrc file?

Right now, I have to do something like this:

```
plt.plot(x, y, '--', dashes=(3,1))
```

I want to put the option "dashes=(3,1)" into the matplotlibrc, but could not find anything about it.

Thanks

EDIT:
For clarification: I don't want to set this globally, but for a stylesheet (http://matplotlib.org/users/style_sheets.html), where the default dash style is too coarse, because the style is for small images for a publication.

Comment: You can see in this dict `matplotlib.rcParams`. I try this `[k for k in matplotlib.rcParams.keys() if 'dashes' in k]` but it return an empty list. If you peel the dict maybe you find something..

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to reuse this particular style a lot, you can simply create a partial function that sets a default for `dashes=` parameter.

```
import functools
dashed_plot = functools.partial(plt.plot, dashes=(3, 1))
```

(It's not necessary to specify `linestyle=` when using the `dashes` keyword parameter).

The rcfile is for other things such as what rendering backend to use, that should be set globally.  I wonder why you want to enforce a dash style for everything as an rc option.

Comment: Thanks. The reason, why I want this, is that I define various custom styles, that I import via plt.style.use('mystyle'), see http://matplotlib.org/users/style_sheets.html. One is for graphics that fit into one column of my text, i.e. the width is only 3.4 inch. For that style I set all fonts/lines accordingly small, but the default dash style is too coarse then. If I change the style to, for instance, a two-column width, I have to change the dashes parameter.